# PHP Form with mixed input (file and text)

Tags: php, forms, post, enctype

i have the following form in html:

```
 <form id="signguestbook" class="form-horizontal" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Uw naam</label>
   <div class="controls"><input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Uw naam"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
   <div class="controls"><input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"><span class="maildisclaimer">(uw e-mailadres zal niet op onze site verschijnen)</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="inputText">Uw ervaring:</label>
   <div class="controls"><textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="inputText" placeholder="Geef hier mee hoe u uw verblijf ervaren heeft!"></textarea></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="inputPhoto">Foto:</label>
   <div class="controls"><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <div class="controls"><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Versturen" /></div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

With twitter bootstrap it looks OK with that lay-out.

Then I have a upload.php with following test code:

```
 <?php
  if ($_POST["inputName"]) {
echo "Naam: " . $_POST["inputName"] . "<br />";
  }
  if ($_POST["inputEmail"]) {
echo "Mail: " . $_POST["inputEmail"] . "<br />";
  }
  if ($_POST["inputText"]) {
echo "Text: " . $_POST["inputText"] . "<br />";
  }
  // photo is the name of our file input field
  if ($_FILES['photo']['error'] > 0) {
   echo "Error: " . $_FILES['photo']['error'] . "<br />";
  } else {
   echo "File name: " . $_FILES['photo']['name'] . "<br />";
   echo "File type: " . $_FILES['photo']['type'] . "<br />";
   echo "File size: " . ($_FILES['photo']['size'] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
   echo "Temp path: " . $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  }
  ?>
```

I didn't expect any errors here but I get the following:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: inputName in /var/www/greze/upload.php on line 3
 Notice: Undefined index: inputEmail in /var/www/greze/upload.php on line 6
 Notice: Undefined index: inputText in /var/www/greze/upload.php on line 9
 File name: 3479331713.pdf
 File type: application/pdf
 File size: 230.8388671875 Kb
 Temp path: /tmp/phpJ4z0FV
```

My file gets recognized, but no $_POST variables. When I do var_dump($_POST) its an empty array. So it should be something in my form, but I've set it to post and the enctype is correct (as I recall)....

I must admit that my coding is off and it's been a while.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["inputName"])) {`

Comment: Only your `file` field is named. Change `<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Uw naam">` to `<input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Uw naam">` and do the same for the rest.

Comment: They have to be the `name` of the input element, not the `id`, to be passed to the server on submit.

Comment: Then in your PHP handler, do `$inputName=$_POST['inputName'];` and do the same for the rest.

Answer (score 3):

These are just notices. They appear because you try to use `$_POST` array with an index that doensn't exist.

Instead of

```
  if ($_POST["inputName"]) {
```

use

```
  if (!empty($_POST["inputName"])) {
```

Other will tell you to use `isset()`, but it won't do what you want. `isset()` function just checks if variable exists. But here you also expect this variable to ba boolean true, which mans they can't be empty too. Here, `empty` function checks both if variable exists and is not empty.

Moreover there is no `name` attribute in your `input` elements. They are identidied by `name` and not `id` as you expect.

Comment: True (about empty), but every input gets validated a bit later in the code so isset wouldn't be wrong. The validation should find the empty values.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `isset` method to test whether the POST global variable has been populated.

For example:

```
if (isset($_POST["inputName"])) {
  echo "Naam: " . $_POST["inputName"] . "<br />";
}
```

Also, give the `<input>` elements a `name` value which is the same as the POST variable that you're expecting with the request.

Answer (score 1):

Your input fields does not have a `name` attribute. Change it to:

```
<input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Uw naam">
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
```

Also, make sure you add a name attribute for your submit button for the use-case mentioned below:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn" value="Versturen" />
```

I also recommend using `isset()` to check if the form was actually submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {

// your PHP code here

}
```

That way, you can make sure that the form is submitted before trying to access the form input values.

And, in your PHP code, you're using `$_POST` values over and over. Why not store them as variables and re-use as needed?

With the corrections, your PHP code should look like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //if form submitted

    $name = $_POST["inputName"];
    $email = $_POST["inputEmail"];
    $text = $_POST["inputText"];

    if ($name) {
    echo "Naam: " . $name . "<br />";
    }
    if ($email) {
    echo "Mail: " . $_POST["inputEmail"] . "<br />";
    }
    if ($text) {
    echo "Text: " . $text . "<br />";
    }

    // photo is the name of our file input field
    if ($_FILES['photo']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES['photo']['error'] . "<br />";
    } else {
    echo "File name: " . $_FILES['photo']['name'] . "<br />";
    echo "File type: " . $_FILES['photo']['type'] . "<br />";
    echo "File size: " . ($_FILES['photo']['size'] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp path: " . $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!